# Posting Twitter/Facebook-Status without authenticating?

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, facebook, twitter

I'm currently working my way through the [facebook-iphone-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) and the [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) and I'm wondering why this all has to be so hard.

I'm not planning to access any data from the two social networks, just allow the users of my app to post a message as their status/update.

Now after I installed the facebook-iphone-sdk I realized they just send you to safari to authenticate at facebook and then back into your app.
Now this seems overly complicated for the users of my app, if they just want to post they don't have to go back.

Isn't there a way, I could just call something like

```
http://api.twitter.com/version/statuses/update?text="this is the new status text"
```

?

---

EDIT:
The first answer

```
http://twitter.com/home?status=[URL ENCODED TWEET].
```

is exactly what I need.
Unfortunately this works perfectly on the Laptop, though if you are not already logged in on the iPhone, you will be presented with a a screen where one has to press "login" once. (at the url "mobile.twitter.com/home?status=[]").
Pressing login there links you to "mobile.twitter.com/session/new" without the status argument and so once you are authenticated the status message is lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL you're looking for is:

```
http://twitter.com/home?status=[URL ENCODED TWEET].
```

This will open up a window of twitter and, if logged in, populate that tweet into the Tweet box.

For Facebook Share, the URL is

```
http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://SHAREURLGOESHERE
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. For iPhone-Users I still had to use "NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding" to encode the message. Unfortunately if I'm not already logged in, the mobile version of twitter seems to forget the string through the login-process. I'll have to delve further into that.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of sample code that comes with the facebook-iphone-SDK. If you were to allow the user to pubish without authorizing it chances are apple would deny it.